# Joomla - How to fix this link in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I need help please.

Hi,

I have this [link](http://csvr.org.za/component/customproperties/?task=tag&tagName=publications%20by%20author:Dix-Peek%20D%20&Itemid=2#top) (View Publications) on this [page](http://csvr.org.za/148-about-us/staff/1892-dominique-dix-peek-) that I need to fix.

Seems like I need to create a module to publish all articles written by the author named "dominique-dix-peek-".

I have no clue what to do.

Comment: Please can you help !

Comment: Might be you need have this Link[link]{http://csvr.org.za/component/customproperties/tag/176?Itemid=2} for author named "dominique-dix-peek". Cross check how you assign the link

Comment: Hi Chole, If the below my answer post is fix your problem, then please accept it, So that we will understand that, your issue is fixed.

Comment: Sorry for that.

Comment: It was not a problem at all. I'm glad I could be of assistance to you.

Comment: I wanted to do that but I wasn't seeing how to do so, using small comment  box. Anyway, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be you need have this Link[link]{csvr.org.za/component/customproperties/tag/176?It‌​emid=2} for author named "dominique-dix-peek". Cross check how you assign the link

Thanks & Regards,
Kaif